C# same name Override Method and Normal method with different type of argument
Here is code which I ran in Visual Studio, but I don't understand the output:
public abstract class AbstractClass
{
    public virtual void Display(int i)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Abstract Class Virtual Display Method");
    }
}

public class Myclass : AbstractClass
{
    public override void Display(int i)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Abstract Class Override Display Method");
    }

    public void Display(object i)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Derived Class Normal Display Method");
    }
}

class MainClass
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Myclass obj = new Myclass();
        int i = 1;
        obj.Display(i);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}

The output is
Derived Class Normal Display Method     // I was expecting: Abstract Class Override Display Method`

Can anyone help me understand why I am getting this output?

Same question: C# method override resolution weirdness

From c# language spec, overload resolution

Each of these contexts defines the set of candidate function members and the list of arguments in its own unique way. For instance, the set of candidates for a method invocation does not include methods marked override (§12.5), and methods in a base class are not candidates if any method in a derived class is applicable (§12.8.9.2).

(emphasis mine)
This basically means that if you have two overloads of a method, and both of them can be chosen as the overload to invoke, and one overrides a method in your base class, then that method will not be invoked.
Note that this only applies if there's an implicit conversion between the types of the parameters in the call site and the types of the arguments in the method signature. For instance, if your Display method was with the type string, it wouldn't be invoked:
public abstract class AbstractClass
{
    public virtual void Display(int i)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Abstract Class Virtual Display Method");
    }
}
public class Myclass : AbstractClass
{
    // This overload would be chosen since int can't be implicitly converted to a string
    public override void Display(int i)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Abstract Class Override Display Method");
    }

    public void Display(string i)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Derived Class Normal Display Method");
    }
}

